# code in cellForRowAt be called after code in cell's class

Tags: swift, uitableview

I have a question about the order of code execute with cellForRowAt

This is my cellForRowAt function

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as! MyTableViewCell
    print(1)
    return cell
}
```

This is my code in my MyTableViewCell.swift

```
override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

    print(2)
}
```

When I run my code. The console log print this result

```
2
1
```

So, my code in my cell's class run before code in cellForRowAt.

But, I want my code in my cell's class run after code in cellForRowAt.
I want the result like this:

```
1
2
```

How can I do like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your `MyTableViewCell.swift` add a function:

```
func doMyStuff() {
    print(2)
}
```

back again to your `cellForRowAtIndexPath`:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as! MyTableViewCell
    print(1)
    cell.doMyStuff()
    return cell
}
```

Comment: Thanks. That is what I need!

Answer (score 0):

Try to do that stuff not in the init function, but in the awakeFromNib

```
override func awakeFromNib(){
super.awakeFromNib()
//stuff
}
```

Comment: I use tableView.dequeueReusableCell to create tableViewCell not from IB so awakeFromNib will not run :(

Comment: I see you are using *MyTableViewCell*. Well, in that class you override awakeFromNib. This is, of course, if MyTableViewCell inherits from TableViewCell

Comment: But I do not use IB to create TableView. I Create TableView programmatically, so that I have to use init(style: reuseIdentifier) instead of using awakeFromNib()

Comment: Then, you can use a function and call it before *return cell*. Or use willDisplay, that is called when the cell is about to get visible

Comment: Thank you!
Create a new function in Cell's Class and call it before return cell solved my problem. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom cell class with the style specifications and then when you instantiate a cell in cellForRowAtIndexPath you can use your custom cell class. So, something like this:

```
myCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("topicCell") as!     topicTableViewCell
```

Where topicTableViewCell is your own UITableViewCell class